# margin:0 auto div improper arrangement on zoom

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar (actually two) - The one in grey(in the image below) and the white one below it. Both have a width of `1000px` and have the attribute of `margin:0 auto;` in their CSS. Have a look at the live one in full screen at http://jsfiddle.net/M2bE2/embedded/result/ and http://jsfiddle.net/M2bE2/ for the output and the code

[image: Wrong Navigation]

I hope that you have got a basic idea of idea of my navigation. Ok then, my problem goes like this. When you zoom out, the white-nav(The second one) gets improperly arranged. The image above shows the improper arrangement on zoom out. I cannot figure out the problem which is causing it. In the output, the disarrangement is after quite zooming out. But, in my real project the problem is even more(It gets disarranged after only a little zoom in or out ).  Please analyze the code and tell me where am I going wrong. I have made the code in my fiddle clean for you to understand. Any help **will be appreciated**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean zoom like zooming on a phone / the browser zoom? because on chrome I don't see any miss arangement.

Comment: @JustGage ...yeah agreed. But using, firefox, the error is being shown. Try using it. P.S. In Chrome the error shows up when you zoom out to 25%

Comment: If you want to make it really structured I would recomend a table. I know some people think they are a unrepentable sin but really their use is to keep things in a structured way and they will always work in any browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the login and register buttons. They are both floating right. Because of this they fill the space the bottom nav needs. If you limit their size, clear the `float`, etc it fixes the issue.

With them removed (easiest solution)
http://jsfiddle.net/M2bE2/2

Comment: Also note the red div, meaning you have a validation error (extra close)

Comment: Take the clear out of the div container and put it between the two, that works

Comment: But P.S. The link which you gave still gives incorrect output...The correct on will be http://jsfiddle.net/M2bE2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Without the overflow:auto in the .white-nav's CSS-Attributes it seems to work.

```
.white-nav {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto; /* Kick it */
}
```